# Probability question on finding number of ways to label all boxes incorrectly with respect to the color of the ball they contain

Tags: probability, permutations

**Question:**

There are balls of 5 different colors - yellow, blue, red, green and white. A worker has to separate these balls as per their colors into different boxes and label them with corresponding colored labels. The worker, after separating the balls, sealed the boxes and labelled the boxes at random. 
What is the probability that all the boxes are labelled incorrectly?

**Progress made so far:**

Was not able to find a pattern for all labels being incorrect.
 So, tried it the other way around:
Let A => event of getting all labels incorrect 
Let B => event of getting at-least one label correct 
We can write **P(A) = 1 - P(B)** 
But finding P(B) seems to be equally challenging as finding P(A)

Any leads on this is much appreciated

Thanks-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of ways of getting all the labels wrong is called the [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement). For $5$ items the number of derangements (sometimes shown as $!5$) is $44$.

There are two simple calculation methods

- derangements have a recurrence formula of $!n = (n - 1) (!(n-1) + !(n-2)) $
- the value can be calculated directly as $!n = \dfrac{n!}{e}$, to the nearest integer.

This second derivation immediately gives an approximate answer to your question of $\frac{1}{e} = 0.367879...$. The exact answer is $\frac{44}{120} = \frac{11}{30} = 0.36666... $.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that he marks the first one wrong is 4/5. Then 3/4. Then 2/3. then 1/2. So $4/5 \cdot 3/4 \cdot 2/3 \cdot 1/2$.

Comment: Just because the first four are wrong, it does not mean the last one is also incorrect.